# Enforcing the ANSI C standard in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

Is there an option I can change in Eclipse to make sure that my code has got to be ANSI C-compliant before it can be compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Tool Settings > Miscellaneous > "Support ANSI programs"

Comment: Wait I found it. I have to check "Support ANSI programs" as you said, but apparently I also have to check the -Wall and -pedantic options.